# GetAvailableWebTemplates returns nothing

Tags: sharepoint, templates

i am trying to create a site from a site template, but i cant seem to get the appropriate site template. in fact, i cant seem to get any site template. i know that there are templates installed, since i can see them listed in the solution gallery, and they are all activated.

ive tried everything i can find to try, but still my "templates" variable returns empty.

```
foreach (SPLanguage lang in web.RegionalSettings.InstalledLanguages)
{
    foreach (SPWebTemplate template in web.Site.GetWebTemplates((uint)lang.LCID))
    {
        if (template.IsCustomTemplate)
        {
            templates.Add(template.Title, template);
        }
    }
    foreach (SPWebTemplate template in web.Site.GetCustomWebTemplates((uint)lang.LCID))
    {
        if (template.IsCustomTemplate && !templates.ContainsKey(template.Title))
        {
            templates.Add(template.Title, template);
        }
    }
    foreach (SPWebTemplate template in web.GetAvailableWebTemplates((uint)lang.LCID, true))
    {
        if (template.IsCustomTemplate && !templates.ContainsKey(template.Title))
        {
            templates.Add(template.Title, template);
        }
    }
    foreach (SPWebTemplate template in web.GetAvailableCrossLanguageWebTemplates())
    {
        if (template.IsCustomTemplate && !templates.ContainsKey(template.Title))
        {
            templates.Add(template.Title, template);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe IsCustomTemplate is not your friend

I try this (PowerShell)
    Start-SPAssignment -Global
    $w = Get-SPWeb -Identity 'http://............'
    $ils=$w.RegionalSettings.InstalledLanguages

```
$ils |  %{

    $lcid = $_.LCID
    $lcid
    $wts=$w.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1031, $true)
    $wts = $wts | ?{ -not $_.IsRootWebOnly}
    $wts | ft -Property Lcid,Name,Title,DisplayCategory
}


$w=$null
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

flori